# SQL - Select all after specific substring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a field with data:  "abc h0h0h0-def"

How can i pull just "def" from this, or whatever may be after "h0h0h0-"?

I have tried:
`right(col,CHARINDEX('h0h0h0-',reverse(col)) - 1)`

But I receive the following error:
"Invalid length parameter pass to the RIGHT function"

This is in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to handle strings that don't have this format:

```
(case when reverse(col) like 'h0h0h0-%'
      then right(col, charindex('h0h0h0-', reverse(col)) - 1)
      else col
  end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a solution that uses PATINDEX.

```
SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%h0h0h0-%', col)+LEN('h0h0h0-'), LEN(col))
```

**Test snippet:**

```
declare @Test table (col varchar(30));
insert into @Test values
('merry h0h0h0-christmas'),
('rudolf');

select col
, SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%h0h0h0-%', col)+LEN('h0h0h0-'), LEN(col)) as [behind the h0h0h0-]
from @Test;
```

**Returns:**

```
col                     behind the h0h0h0-
---                     ---------
merry h0h0h0-christmas  christmas
rudolf
```